# How to set Where Clause for a inner ng-repeat in angularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, where-clause, angularjs-filter

I'm having a two JSON array,

```
$scope.color = [
    {
        "cInstId": 1,
        "cInstTitle": "Blue"
    },
    {
        "cInstId": 2,
        "cInstTitle": "Green"
    },
    {
        "cInstId": 3,
        "cInstTitle": "Red"
    },
    {
        "cInstId": 4,
        "cInstTitle": "Orange"
    },
    {
        "cInstId": 5,
        "cInstTitle": "Violet"
    }
];

$scope.data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "cTitle": "One",
        "cInstId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "cTitle": "Two",
        "cInstId": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "cTitle": "Three",
        "cInstId": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "cTitle": "Four",
        "cInstId": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "cTitle": "Five",
        "cInstId": 4
    }
];
```

Now I need to print all the `$scope.color` with associated `$scope.data` with a common key value in `cInstId`

```
<div ng-repeat="col in color">
    <p>{{ col.cInstTitle }}</p>
    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="dataItem in data| **WHERE CLAUSE dataItem.cInstId = col.cInstId** ">
            <div>{{ dataItem.cTitle }}</div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `filter` as follows

```
<li ng-repeat="dataItem in data | filter : {cInstId: col.cInstId}">
    <div>{{ dataItem.cTitle }}</div>
</li>
```

The following filter criteria will filter `dataItem` objects in `data` array based on `cIntsId` key.

```
filter : {cInstId: col.cInstId}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/y962yQAP5w7d7OF2XM49?p=preview)

Answer (score 8):

You could use just `ng-if` clause. Use this line -

```
<li ng-if="dataItem.cInstId=== col.cInstId" ng-repeat="dataItem in data">
```